# Go line up in windows console

Tags: c++, winapi, iostream

It seems that you can go back one character from current line in the console using `\b`. However, the console doesn't seem to be able to jump one line up.

I want to mark invalid user input *red*. After typping input, user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> which put's unerasable new line in the console.

My plan was to do the following:

1. Check the `input` for validity.
2. If it's invalid, print `input.length()+1` times `\b`
3. Turn console color red
4. Print the `input`, print `\n`

But, the `\b` will not jump back to the line where user input is. So I have plan B:

1. Remember the length of string that was before user input (`query_string`)
2. Check the `input` for validity.
3. If it's invalid, go line up (where the input was entered)
4. Jump to `query_string.length()` character
5. Turn console color red
6. Print the `input`, print `\n`

However, I don't know how to do this using the [console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx). While I'm at it, [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways you can do this.

One way is, as @chris implied in a comment, is to save the cursor position of where the user started typing. When you find bad input, you set the cursor back to that position and change the text attribute of the characters he entered.

You probably don't want to scroll the window back up one line. If you do, then the window will appear to "jump" when the user makes an error. It's a really jarring user interface experience. But if you want to try, you can call [ScrollConsoleScreenBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Another way to do it would be to [change the console mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that it doesn't automatically echo characters when the user types them. Instead, you read each character individually, append it to your input buffer, and when the user presses Enter you validate. If the input is valid, you issue a newline to move to the next line. Otherwise you back up and highlight the erroneous input. This sounds like a lot more work, but it's not that difficult and it results in a much better UI experience.